# How to restore a encrypted password properly and do I need it at all?

Tags: mongodb, heroku, bcrypt

I'm using MongoDB and Node.js to create a web app. 
My users should be able to connect to their databases using connection strings, what have a password as a part.

Firstly I thought about bcrypt but I can't use it because in this case, I have to require users to enter their database passwords every time when they want to connect to their databases.

Then I found the crypto module and crypto.createDecipher can decrypt encrypted password but I have to store a key somewhere. So I store my key as Heroku environment variable.

So my questions are:

1. Do I implement a proper approach? Maybe there is more secure way to
       gain the same?
2. If not is it safe to store a key as Heroku env
       variable?

If you think it's a bad idea to store passwords even encrypted please tell me then how other services do it, for example, such as provide you the access to your databases.
Thanks

Comment: 1. Hashed passwords, in particular cryptographic hashes can not be reversed. 2. Assume attackers will gain admin access the server and protect against that.

Comment: @zaph thanks for your comment. I found I put a little bit wrong information into the question. Please see the updated question.